# DataGridView's button is not refreshing the Items in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview, refresh, reload

I have a DataGridView in my WPF application where users can add new items with some TextBoxes like this:

```
        SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection();
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
        sc.ConnectionString = ("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=testtable;Integrated Security=SSPI");
        sc.Open();
        com.Connection = sc;
        com.CommandText = ("INSERT INTO Hianyok2 (Title, ID, Date) VALUES ('" + Title.Text + "', '" + ID.Text + "', '" + Date.Text + "');");
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sc.Close();
```

When I tested the app, I could add new items to the database with them, but the datagridview not refreshing automatically. If I close the window and I reopen it, the datagridview shows the newly added rows. The "adding button" contains these lines:

```
        Hianytabla.ItemsSource = null;
        Hianytabla.ItemsSource = dc.Hianyok2s;
        Hianytabla.Items.Refresh();
```

When I was searching for the solution, I found similars like this, but they are not working for me. Could you please help me, how can this button work well?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: `DataGridView` is Winforms control not WPF

Answer (score 0):

**Refresh()** method does not updates the latest Item source.

You have to call the method, on the refresh button, in which you are getting the data from the Database again e.g **GetHianyok2FromDB()** get the dataset/datatable and assign that again to your DataGrid with the **ItemSource()** Method.